# Hide tab based on title

Tags: javascript, css, tabs

I am trying to close a specific tab when someone prints my webpage as it's secondary information.

Is it possible to close a tab based on it's title? I am unable to add an id/class to the tab myself and I can't use the generated id as I would need to apply a hide rule to each arbitrary tab id which just isn't practical.

I can't use the nth child rule as the amount and position of tabs vary from page to page. The only solution I can think of, is to hide a tab based on it's title.

Below is the html from the page - so if I wanted to hide all tabs with title "Additional Info" - is there a way to do this?

```
<a href="#tab-1415272795947-4-9" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">Additional Info</a>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose every tab has the same class `ui-tabs-anchor`. If so, you can do something like this:

```js
// Get all tabelements
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-tabs-anchor');

// Loop through each tabelement
for (var i = 0, j = tabs.length; i < j; i++) {
  // If the innerHTML equals 'Additional Info'
  if (tabs[i].innerHTML === 'Additional Info') {
    // Hide the element
    tabs[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#tab-1415272795947-4-9" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">Other Info</a>
<a href="#tab-1415272795947-4-9" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">Additional Info</a>
<a href="#tab-1415272795947-4-9" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">More Info</a>
<a href="#tab-1415272795947-4-9" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-4">Additional Info</a>
<a href="#tab-1415272795947-4-9" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-5">Different Info</a>
<a href="#tab-1415272795947-4-9" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-6">Additional Info</a>
```

Comment: Brilliant - this is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Not to push my luck - but I am a competent coder but new to Wordpress and have limited javascript skills. Any advice on how to enqueue this into functions.php? I have tried, but the website cracks it, so I'm obviously doing it wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem :) If my answer solves your issue you can press the checkmark next to my question/upvote it.

Comment: I have not much experience with Wordpress. But I do know this is not something you put in the functions.php. You can place it in the footer.php or something like that.

Comment: Hi there - I can't actually test it until I work out how to enqueue it into function.php - do you happen to know how to do this Otherwise, as soon as I work it out myself and it works, I can check it :)

Comment: Okay thanks - I will try and work it out. From what I have read, I was under the impression functions.php was the correct place but perhaps I have misunderstood. Will check mark it for you once it works - though it appears to be correct in your code snippit :)

Comment: Maybe you can do something like this: make a new file and copy my javascript into it. Save it as `tabhider.js` or something and put it in your theme folder. Then put this in the functions.php: `function tabhider_enqueue_script() { wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', 'tabhider.js', false ); } add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tabhider_enqueue_script' );`